# Change the screen resolution of the Kuman screen

Tags: pi-3

I have bought a Kuman screen 3.5" (320 x 480). I want change the screen resolution. But I don't know how to make this change: https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B01FX7909Q/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I don't what is the resolution I must use: http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible you are stuck with the fixed resolution of the screen (320*480). You may be able to reduce the resolution, but I doubt that is what you want to do.

The options you point out in the RPi config link above are for screens connected via composite and HDMI ports.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to unplug and plug in the raspberry pi while connected to the screen. It will detect and display the max resolution.

Comment: I don't think this will work with the OP's screen which mounts to the GPIO pins.